# Referential Integrity with Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I am working on a project that uses a graph database to hold click data for a search engine. The nodes can be search terms or urls, and the edges hold a weight attribute, and a percentage of times that search led to someone clicking that URL.

`Number of times the URL was clicked / Number of times term was searched`

My issue is that when I update the edges, the percentage will be accurate, but if I later update the search term node and the searched count changes, the edge will no longer have the correct percentage. Is there a way in Neo4j to keep referential integrity? like a foreign key type thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following info might be helpful.

If you stored the number of clicks instead of the percentage, there is no way to get inconsistent data. For example:

```
(:Term {id: 1, nSearches: 123})-[:HAS_URL {weight: 2, nClicks: 17}]->(:Url {id: 2})
```

With this data model, you'd calculate the percentage whenever you needed it.

For example, to find the 10 terms that have the highest percentage of visits to a specific URL:

```
MATCH (term:Term)-[r:HAS_URL]->(url:Url {id: 2})
RETURN url, term
ORDER BY r.nClicks/term.nSearches DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But notice that the inverse query (find the 10 URLs that have the highest percentage of visits from a specific term) does not even require that you calculate the percentage! This is because in this case the percentages all have the same denominator. So, you can just use `nClicks` for sorting:

```
MATCH (term:Term {id: 1})-[r:HAS_URL]->(url:Url)
RETURN term, url
ORDER BY r.nClicks DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, neo4j doesn't support this.  You can still do it, with one of two methods.  I'll tell you what they both are, then make a recommendation.

Relative to your relational database, I don't think you're looking for a foreign key or "referential integrity" -- I think what you're looking for is more like a trigger.  A trigger is like a function or procedure that executes when data changes.  In your case, it'd probably be good to have trigger functions that re-calculated all of the weight percentages on incident edges.

**Option 1** - The capable Max De Marzi [has got you covered there](http://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/) with a description of how you can do triggers in neo4j.  Spoiling the surprise, there's a `TransactionEventHandler` in the java API.  When the right kind of transaction comes through, you can catch that and do extra stuff.

**Option 2** - the server provides an [extension/plugin mechanism](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html) so that you could write this on your own.  This is a big hammer, it can do just about anything, but it's harder to wield, too.

I'd recommend you look into Max's post and the `TransactionEventHandler`.  You might then implement `public void afterCommit(TransactionData transactionData, Object o)`.  In that method, you'd check out the transaction data to see if it was something of interest (not all transactions would be of interest).   If the transaction updated a search term node or searched count changes, then I'd go do your recomputation, fix your weights, and you should be good.